# Unity 5.6 null error

Tags: unity-game-engine

I installed unity 5.6 64-bit today. But I had a problem loading previous unity projects.

When I am loading a previous unity project, an empty error (without description) is appearing and preventing me from running the playmode.

Editor Log: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7nX9jrUen3Kbmp6NU9sak9RTk0

[image]

Comment: And you can't jump to line for it either?

Comment: no nothing ? its preventing me from running the application.

Comment: Try removing all the possible remaining files from your old Unity version and reinstall version 5.6.

Comment: Also, you can try to read the error that was not displayed in the Editor by showing the [Editor Log](http://i.imgur.com/HoJwjDC.png).

Comment: I removed everything and reinstalled unity, and still the same error. where to find the error in Editor Log ?

Comment: Make a pastebin or anything of your log and share the link there, so we can check.

Comment: I added the Editor Log.....Thank you for your help.

Comment: I see the following line:
"Incomplete mesh data in Sprite. Please reimport or recreate the Sprite."
Try to reimport your entire project folder. It might solve the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142704/discussion-between-adam-and-isuka).

Comment: There's actually a compilation failure above in the log "-----CompilerOutput:-stdout--exitcode: -1073741819--compilationhadfailure: True--outfile: Temp/Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll"

Comment: what does that mean ? how to fix it ?

Comment: I solved it by Changing system region English, you can do it in control panel -> language setting -> region - > Administrative tab - > change system location

Answer (score 0):

When you scroll all the way down in the editor log, it returned `Incomplete mesh data in Sprite. Please reimport or recreate the Sprite.`. I think that means that you imported your sprites the wrong way.

Also, it seems like the language isn't English. Try setting your language to English and see if it still appears the same way. Another issue might be that there's something wrong with one of your scripts because it said this:

```
 "-----CompilerOutput:-stdout--exitcode: -1073741819--compilationhadfailure: True--outfile: Temp/Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll
-----CompilerOutput:-stderr----------
-----EndCompilerOutput---------------"
```

Hopefully this helped you in any way! :D

Comment: Note that this question is from four years ago in **2017** ... and it was also back then on Jul 11 2017 when [OP already stated that the issue was solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43627871/unity-5-6-null-error/67694376#comment77031836_43627871) `by Changing system region English, you can do it in control panel -> language setting -> region - > Administrative tab - > change system location`